# Meteor's FlowRouter.url() returning IP address of host, not FQDN

Tags: meteor, flow-router

When calling:

`FlowRouter.url("myRouteName");`

I'm getting the IP address of the server, i.e

`"http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/loggedin/my-route"`

Instead of the FQDN, i.e

`"http://example.com/loggedin/my-route"`

Any idea how this can be configured properly?

Thanks.

---

Comment: Is your `ROOT_URL` environment variable set?

Comment: Good question. Can this handle multiple sites though? The instance is accessed via example.xyz, example.co.uk, example.in etc.

Comment: `ROOT_URL` can only specify one URL, but you could do one of two things: (1) specify a single URL like `example.xyz` and your instance will always use that URL `Meteor.absoluteUrl` regardless of that URL was used to access the site. (2) Have one instance per possible URL with the correct `ROOT_URL` for each instance. (2) may be what you want but it depends on how many possible domains you are using, and if the number is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. [Source](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/blob/master/lib/router.js).

```
Router.prototype.url = function() {
  // We need to remove the leading base path, or "/", as it will be inserted
  // automatically by `Meteor.absoluteUrl` as documented in:
  // http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl
  var completePath = this.path.apply(this, arguments);
  var basePath = this._basePath || '/';
  var pathWithoutBase = completePath.replace(new RegExp('^' + basePath), '');
  return Meteor.absoluteUrl(pathWithoutBase);
};
```

So it seems FlowRouter is using `Meteor.absoluteUrl`.

Now the absolute path can be set with `Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = "http://example.com"` However this isn't the correct approach for me, as my app can actually serve multiple domain names.

So I'll have to write my own function, which extracts the FQDN from the client, ad hoc.

```
flowRouterUrl = function(id, params, queryParams) {
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + FlowRouter.path(id, params, queryParams);
}

flowRouterUrl("myRoute");
```

returns

`http://example.com/loggedin/my-route`

Which is what I'm after.